# nextElementSibling not working in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have this problem setting this script to work in my Wordpress site. The code uses nextElementSibling to get the same level element (to make an accordion) as shown in the W3schools page: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion

```
<style>
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc; 
}
div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
}
</style>

<h2>Accordion</h2>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
       var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
       window.alert(panel);
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

You can see that my script is exactly the same as in the W3Schools page, except for the window alert line, which I'm using to see what is happening. Well, nothing happens, when I press any of the buttons, nothing shows. But I'm suspecting something is not working with nextElementSibling, because the window alert shows me "null", and the alert in the example page shows me "[object HTMLDivElement]".

So I think nextElementSibling is not assigning the "panel" class divs to the panel variable.

The question is why it works in the example page and not in my Wordpress post?

Additionally, this script works perfectly in my same post (so the error is not the javascript implementation): https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_hide_show

Please help.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what tab you're in as the output is still applied on saving.

Comment: No, that's a good guess, but i work only in the html tab.

Comment: This code works as expected - perhaps post a link where it doesn't work.

Comment: Anyway, yes it is a Wordpress thing because I copy pasted the same code I used there in a blank text file, renamed it to .html and loaded it in Chrome, and it works fine.

Comment: Here is a page where you can watch the problem: http://juliushernandez.mx/lab/proy-test2/ -- Sorry, it can't access, I'm gonna give you another public link in some minutes.

Comment: @MauricioPraga I think you have to logged in to see that page

Comment: Sorry, please give me some minutes and I will post here a public link

Comment: Here is a public link and the same behavior: http://controljet.com.mx/test/accordion-test/

Comment: Yeah it is like I said your button is being wrapped in a p tag by wordpress

Comment: Try removing any line breaks and spaces between the button and the div.

Comment: Ok, but how do I avoid that? And I write in in the html section, there is no no spaces between the button line and the div line. Now I've put together all buttons and div lines and the result is the same.

Comment: @MauricioPraga You can add remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); and resave, which removes auto p tags being appended to you html. Or we could modify the javascript to something other than next sibling.

Comment: (Haven't seen your previous comment) Oh, yes, it worked... I convert all the buttons to div and it worked, now the problem is not the nextElementSibling as I first thougt. It works with divs and not with buttons, because buttons keeps being wrapped in p tags. Please post your answer outside here because this system is telling me to avoid extended discussions, thanks.

Comment: @MauricioPraga Sorry about that. I've posted an answer that covers the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress auto p tags are wrapping your button element in a paragraph, so the div with the panel class is no longer your next sibling

```
<p><button class="accordion">Section 1</button></p>
```

You can update your next sibling line to `parentElement.nextElementSibling` and it should work or you can disable auto p tags by adding the below to your functions file or modify your js to select the parent p element before using next sibling.

```
<?php remove_filter ('the_content', 'wpautop'); ?>
```

Comment: Removing the auto <p> filter from  the_content would be a site wide change. You can just call `get_the_content()` and the <p> tags are negated.

Comment: @jeh That still comes with drawbacks with like short codes not being parsed and needing to build a specific template. There are plugins that handle this better, but I was just providing some quick solutions without going in to templating.

Comment: Interesting! thanks for that. I would like to look into it more myself :)

Comment: @jeh no problem, I don't thing there is a magic bullet for this.

Comment: I'm slow (not so skilled) in this javascript/html thing but I'll try your suggestions, in a couple of hours I'll have some results.

Comment: Well, it finally worked... The real problem was in another more complex site and Wordpress kept putting the p tags. I had to use the Raw-html plugin (as ISZ mentioned), which strips the text out of those annoying tags. I don't know why WP does those strange things by default.